# Example of a square matrix $A$ such that $\mu_A = x^k$ for all $k\ge 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

I want to find an example for each $k \geq 1$, of a square matrix $A$ (of some size) such that $\mu_A(x) = x^k$.

Here $\mu_A(x)$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Please help me.

Comment: What is $\mu_A$? Is $k$ the size of $A$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde given the tag, it would seem that $\mu_A$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Defining the notation is better than hiding it in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&\ddots&\ddots\\&&&&1\\&&&&0\\&&&&&0\\&&&&&&\ddots\\&&&&&&&0}
$$
will have minimal polynomial $\mu_A = x^k$ in which $k-1$ counts the number of $1$s in the above matrix.  Note that the blank entries are zeros; the zeros on the diagonal are explicitly written for clarity.